# Python EWMA with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date    AAPL    TSLA    NESN    FB  ROCH    TOT VISA    JPM
2/1/2019    0.00259 0.00164 0.00122 0.00179 0.00116 0.00023 0.00145 0.00141
3/1/2019    -0.09961    -0.03147    0.02545 -0.02904    0.02241 0.00227 -0.03604    -0.02215
4/1/2019    0.04269 0.0577  0.01679 0.04714 0.01017 0.0293  0.04308 0.03687
7/1/2019    -0.00223    0.05436 -0.01053    0.00072 -0.00881    -0.00184    0.01803 0.0007
8/1/2019    0.01906 0.00116 0.00314 0.03245 0.02633 -0.00313    0.00544 -0.00189
9/1/2019    0.01698 0.00948 0.00928 0.01193 0.00093 0.02196 0.01177 -0.00169
10/1/2019   0.0032  0.01902 0.00776 -0.00021    0.00679 -0.00758    0.00188 -1.00E-04
11/1/2019   -0.00982    0.00664 0.00142 -0.00277    -0.00583    -0.01947    -0.0044 -0.00478
14/1/2019   -0.01504    -0.03703    -0.00095    0.01106 -0.00247    0.00761 -0.00695    0.01031
15/1/2019   0.02047 0.02999 0.00308 0.02449 0.00495 -0.00902    0.00175 0.00733
16/1/2019   0.01222 0.0047  -0.00803    -0.00947    -0.00154    -0.0039 0   0.00806
17/1/2019   0.00594 0.00364 0.00607 0.00515 -0.00062    0.00299 -0.00044    0.0041
```

I would like to end up with an array made of the EWMA (with a lambda: 0.94) for each of the stocks I'm considering as off the last day of my timeseries.
I was able to obtain this with a regular ascending index (0, 1, 2, 3 etc..) but I'm encountering an issue when I'm working with dates.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I created the data frame; changed Date to type datetime; and made Date the index:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''Date    AAPL    TSLA    NESN    FB  ROCH    TOT VISA    JPM
2/1/2019    0.00259 0.00164 0.00122 0.00179 0.00116 0.00023 0.00145 0.00141
3/1/2019    -0.09961    -0.03147    0.02545 -0.02904    0.02241 0.00227 -0.03604    -0.02215
4/1/2019    0.04269 0.0577  0.01679 0.04714 0.01017 0.0293  0.04308 0.03687
7/1/2019    -0.00223    0.05436 -0.01053    0.00072 -0.00881    -0.00184    0.01803 0.0007
8/1/2019    0.01906 0.00116 0.00314 0.03245 0.02633 -0.00313    0.00544 -0.00189
9/1/2019    0.01698 0.00948 0.00928 0.01193 0.00093 0.02196 0.01177 -0.00169
10/1/2019   0.0032  0.01902 0.00776 -0.00021    0.00679 -0.00758    0.00188 -1.00E-04
11/1/2019   -0.00982    0.00664 0.00142 -0.00277    -0.00583    -0.01947    -0.0044 -0.00478
14/1/2019   -0.01504    -0.03703    -0.00095    0.01106 -0.00247    0.00761 -0.00695    0.01031
15/1/2019   0.02047 0.02999 0.00308 0.02449 0.00495 -0.00902    0.00175 0.00733
16/1/2019   0.01222 0.0047  -0.00803    -0.00947    -0.00154    -0.0039 0   0.00806
17/1/2019   0.00594 0.00364 0.00607 0.00515 -0.00062    0.00299 -0.00044    0.0041
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

Then, I applied the `ewm().mean()` method.  You can specify different parameters in the ewm() method, as span may not be what you want

```
df.ewm(span=2).mean().iloc[-1]

AAPL    0.007770
TSLA    0.004901
NESN    0.002509
FB      0.003415
ROCH   -0.000471
TOT     0.000485
VISA   -0.000351
JPM     0.005281
Name: 2019-01-17 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Finally, I believe that `ewma()` was deprecated in pandas (my example was tested with pandas 1.0.5).